# In Android how to find the center point of transparent area in png image file

Tags: android, image-processing, layout

I have problem where i need to add a button on center of transparent area in image.

**Example:**

[image]

according to above image i have hundreds of photo frame and each frame there is a transparent area and i need to add a button on center of this transparent area.

Now i want a solution in which i can get coordinates of "x" programatically.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static PointF getTransparentCenter(Bitmap bitmap, Point viewSize) {
    List<Point> transparentPoints = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < bitmap.getWidth(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < bitmap.getHeight(); j++) {
            int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(i, j);
            if ((pixel & 0xff000000) == 0) {
                //the point color is transparent
                transparentPoints.add(new Point(i, j));
            }
        }
    }
    int totalX = 0;
    int totalY = 0;
    for (Point transparentPoint : transparentPoints) {
        totalX += transparentPoint.x;
        totalY += transparentPoint.y;
    }
    float centerX = (float) totalX / transparentPoints.size();
    float centerY = (float) totalY / transparentPoints.size();
    float x = viewSize.x * centerX / bitmap.getWidth();
    float y = viewSize.y * centerY / bitmap.getHeight();
    return new PointF(x, y);
}
```

I think this is stupid, but I think there's no other way.

Comment: hii thanks for comment and i want to know what you mean by stupid? my question or your answer??

Comment: @NavneetSharma  My answer, for it's performance problem. If the photo to show is load from your server, I think you should store the center position data on your server, and contain these information within the response.

Comment: The photo frames i'm using from my drawables and the are png file formats.
i'm trying to find a programmatic solutions for this problem.